# how optimize htaccess successfully?

Tags: .htaccess, optimization

i have a wordpress site and i want to optimize website by htaccess
this is my gtmetrix analyze
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/akhbartop.com/nDZRjsNK
i want optimize my website without using plugin.before i used wp-rocket but does not effect in my website as well.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
# Block the include-only files.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
#Gzip - compress text, html, javascript, css, xml
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</ifmodule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
#End Gzip
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php|woff|ttf|png|jpg|gif)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|woff|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off
# BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>
# END Remove Last-Modified Header
```

Comment: why the [`FileETag`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#fileetag) is disabled?

Comment: i don't know what codes good for htaccess.if you can help for solve it

Comment: You can have a look at my blog: http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/protect-wordpress-htaccess-wordpress-optimization/

Hope this will help you.